# How to use Xcode static analyzer command line to generate an HTML report of warnings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang-static-analyzer, retain-cycle

I installed llvm and use **scan-build** to statically analyze a very simple demo project. In this project, I intentionally created a retain cycle and Xcode can immediately display a retain cycle warning in the editor. However, if I switch to use the following **scan-build** command line tool, it states that no bugs found and no report is generated in the end.

```
scan-build xcodebuild -workspace RetainCycleDemo.xcworkspace -scheme RetainCycleDemo -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator15.2
```

Here's the retain cycle code snippet.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^aBlock)(void);

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.aBlock = ^{
        NSLog(@"current vc = %p", self);
    };
    self.aBlock();
}
```

What I want to do is use any static analyzer command line tool to find bugs such as ***some*** retain cycles. Since Xcode is able to report warnings in the editor, how can we ask it to generate a report that contains these warnings? Or is there any other command line tools we can use?

Answer (score 0):

If you call scan-build without any checkers, it will use default checkers for analysing. You can check default enabled checker with

```
scan-build --help
```

Checkers with "+" are enabled by default. Within the list, there are some checkers, that work with OSX (for example: osx.OSObjectRetainCount       Check for leaks and improper reference count management for OSObject). To enable checker, use -enable-checker:

```
scan-build -enable-checker osx.OSObjectRetainCount <your compile command>
```

Wish it would help.